# Giving error in ubuntu while installing kite autocomple software

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, kite

Giving this error while installing kite in ubuntu

```
sunbeam@rishi:~--> bash -c "$(wget -q -O - https://linux.kite.com/dls/linux/current)"

This script will install Kite!

We hope you enjoy! If you run into any issues, please report them at https://github.com/kiteco/issue-tracker.

- The Kite Team

Press enter to continue...

Checking to see if all dependencies are installed....

Did not find libXScrnSaver on your system. We can install it now or you can install and re-run this script
Install it now? (you might be asked for your sudo password) [Y/n] y
[sudo] password for sunbeam: 
There are no enabled repos.
 Run "yum repolist all" to see the repos you have.
 You can enable repos with yum-config-manager --enable <repo>
```

how can i resolve this error as i am using ubuntu and i tried some other methods from stackoverflow but it still giving error

Answer (score 3):

Apparently this is a known issue; details/suggested solution here: https://help.kite.com/article/106-linux-install-issues

> Cannot find libXScrnSaver You may also see a message telling you There
> are no enabled repos. This problem can be fixed by running the
> following terminal commands:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxss1
wget -O kite-installer https://linux.kite.com/dls/linux/current
bash kite-installer --download
bash kite-installer --install
```

Answer (score -2):

Download `kite-installer.sh` from `https://www.dropbox.com/s/lcdheyto0hqln77/kite-installer.sh?dl=0`

Then remove the following bolded lines from the `kite-installer.sh`

```sh
if command -v yum >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        if ! yum list installed libXScrnSaver &> /dev/null; then
            echo "Did not find libXScrnSaver on your system. We can install it now or you can install and re-run this script"
            read -r -e -p "Install it now? (you might be asked for your sudo password) [Y/n] " INSTALL
            INSTALL=${INSTALL:-Y}
            if [[ $INSTALL == "Y" || $INSTALL == "y" ]]; then
                sudo yum install -y -q libXScrnSaver
            else
                echo "Please run 'sudo yum install libXScrnSaver' and rerun this script! Exiting now."
                exit 15
            fi
fi
```

Then correct the next line as below

```sh
elif command -v zypper >/dev/null 2>&1; then **---->into---->** if command -v zypper >/dev/null 2>&1; then
```

Now save the file
run the following commands in the terminal window (open the terminal window where the `kite-installer.sh` is saved)

```sh
chmod +x kite-installer.sh
./kite-installer.sh
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Vairava! Can you please explain your answer a bit more detail, i.e. why zypper command is required, and where this dropbox code is written by?